# Soap Wsdl can not connect to host. Old IP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

My goal is to get soap webservice running for OpenEMM. Therefore I configured ws.wsdl with localhost:8080 and the soap connect as well.

Unfortunatelly the host can not be reached due to a wrong IP inside xml. This is the IP including the HTTPS protocol I tried to connect earlier on. To ommit caching problems I configured php.ini to set caching for soap to 0 and restarted apache2. Same result:

```
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://192.168...', '', 1, 0)
```

ws.wsdl:

```
/home/openemm/webservices$ sudo cat ws.wsdl | grep local
     <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/emm_webservice"/>
```

I am wondering where the old 192.168.x IP is comming from. Unfortunateyll one can only see half of the IP inside the log.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by removing the wsdl file inside /tmp